# How to Input a string with 3 different variables like in char and double. Then to parse them into their specific variables

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is have the user enter a line of string. Which consists of three variables/parts that go in three different variables. 
For example: 1234 A 56.78
The 1234 is a transaction number(int),
The A is a location symbol (char) and 
The  56.78 is a transaction amount(double).
Then have these parts go to their specific variable.

Comment: Uae `split()` method `String` class

Answer (score 1):

Use scanner class it is best for this kind of stuff:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( "123 A 52.8" );

    int num = scan.nextInt();
    char a = scan.next().charAt( 0 );
    double num2 = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println( num + " " + a + " " + num2 );
```

Or use split method

```
    String string = "123 A 52.8";

    String[] arr = string.split( "\\s+" );

    int num = Integer.parseInt( arr[0] );
    char a = arr[1].charAt( 0 );
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble( arr[2] );

    System.out.println( num + " " + a + " " + num2 );
```